# end div tag attached to wrong head div tag

Tags: html

The `<div id="header">` should end here `</div> <!-- End of Header Div  -->`, but instead it ends here`</div> <!-- End of notBar Div-->`.

I have the places where my divs are supposed to end in comments. The only div that ends where it is supposed to this div `<div id="mySidebar">`.

Why are the divs ending at the wrong `</div>` 
tag?

**(I am sorry if this is formatted horribly. I don't use this very much, so my formatting and questions are probably horrible.)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Caleb Did This</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Caleb.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="mySidebar">
<a href="javascript:hideMenu()"class="Links" id="close">Close <b>X</b></a>
<a href="" class="Links link">About</a>
<a href="index.html" class="Links link">Home</a>
<a href="" onclick="myAccFunc()" class="Links link">Websites</a>
</div> <!--  End of mySidebar Div  -->
<div id="notBar">
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACZSURBVGhD7djBCcJAGETh1QpiKzakxViDYCtpwSKUNKIzh9wW/pziuLwP3jFhQgzCNgAAMLijuqq7eoTlTd7mjaWb+oTnjaWn6l2clDeWhnkjB5X8jVyUNwIAsk3qFJY3bXZWi+r9oyb0Vt5YmlXvBkl5Y2mYB/Fre6neDRLytk0/rdXff+wAgJ/ggG7HOKBLiwM6AACQr7UvP+370u9envwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Menu Bar" style="width: 35px; height: 40px;" id="menu" onclick="showMenu()"> 
<center class="center">Caleb Did This</center>
</div> <!-- End of Header Div  -->
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/25/12/28/iceland-1768744_960_720.jpg" id="Ice">
<footer>
<p class="pmargin"><span class="gray">Created and designed by</span>
<span class="names">Caleb</span></p>
<p><span class="gray">Lots of help from my uncle</span>
<span class="names">Jonathan</span></p>
<p class="icon"><span class="gray">All Icons were made by</span></p>
<a href="https://icons8.com" class="a"><span class="names">Icons8</span></a>
</footer>
</div> <!-- End of notBar Div-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Caleb.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have misplaced the `<!-- End of notBar Div -->`. That div is closed much earlier (you have ordered the comments on the closing tags incorrectly)...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your "notBar" div is being closed after your footer instead of in your "header" div. Try this:

```
    <div id="header">
    <div id="mySidebar">
        <a href="javascript:hideMenu()"class="Links" id="close">Close <b>X</b></a>
        <a href="" class="Links link">About</a>
        <a href="index.html" class="Links link">Home</a>
        <a href="" onclick="myAccFunc()" class="Links link">Websites</a>
    </div> <!--  End of mySidebar Div  -->
    <div id="notBar">
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACZSURBVGhD7djBCcJAGETh1QpiKzakxViDYCtpwSKUNKIzh9wW/pziuLwP3jFhQgzCNgAAMLijuqq7eoTlTd7mjaWb+oTnjaWn6l2clDeWhnkjB5X8jVyUNwIAsk3qFJY3bXZWi+r9oyb0Vt5YmlXvBkl5Y2mYB/Fre6neDRLytk0/rdXff+wAgJ/ggG7HOKBLiwM6AACQr7UvP+370u9envwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Menu Bar" style="width: 35px; height: 40px;" id="menu" onclick="showMenu()"> 
        <center class="center">Caleb Did This</center>
    </div> <!-- End of notBar Div-->    
</div> <!-- End of Header Div  -->

<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/25/12/28/iceland-1768744_960_720.jpg" id="Ice">
<footer>

    <p class="pmargin"><span class="gray">Created and designed by</span> <span class="names">Caleb</span></p>
    <p><span class="gray">Lots of help from my uncle</span> <span class="names">Jonathan</span></p>
    <p class="icon"><span class="gray">All Icons were made by</span></p> <a href="https://icons8.com" class="a"><span class="names">Icons8</span></a>

</footer>
```

Comment: The notBar div was meant to be any content that is not part of the sidebar. So the footer is supposed to be part of the notBar div.

Answer (score 0):

this is the structure of your document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Caleb Did This</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Caleb.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
     <div id="mySidebar">
            <a href="javascript:hideMenu()"class="Links" id="close">Close <b>X</b></a>
            <a href="" class="Links link">About</a>
            <a href="index.html" class="Links link">Home</a>
            <a href="" onclick="myAccFunc()" class="Links link">Websites</a>
    </div> <!--  End of mySidebar Div  -->
    <div id="notBar">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACZSURBVGhD7djBCcJAGETh1QpiKzakxViDYCtpwSKUNKIzh9wW/pziuLwP3jFhQgzCNgAAMLijuqq7eoTlTd7mjaWb+oTnjaWn6l2clDeWhnkjB5X8jVyUNwIAsk3qFJY3bXZWi+r9oyb0Vt5YmlXvBkl5Y2mYB/Fre6neDRLytk0/rdXff+wAgJ/ggG7HOKBLiwM6AACQr7UvP+370u9envwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Menu Bar" style="width: 35px; height: 40px;" id="menu" onclick="showMenu()"> 
            <center class="center">Caleb Did This</center>
    </div> <!-- End of NotBar  -->

    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/25/12/28/iceland-1768744_960_720.jpg" id="Ice">
    <footer>

            <p class="pmargin"><span class="gray">Created and designed by</span> <span class="names">Caleb</span></p>
            <p><span class="gray">Lots of help from my uncle</span> <span class="names">Jonathan</span></p>
            <p class="icon"><span class="gray">All Icons were made by</span></p> <a href="https://icons8.com" class="a"><span class="names">Icons8</span></a>

     </footer>
</div> <!-- End of header Div-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Caleb.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you want something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Caleb Did This</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Caleb.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div id="mySidebar">
            <a href="javascript:hideMenu()"class="Links" id="close">Close <b>X</b></a>
            <a href="" class="Links link">About</a>
            <a href="index.html" class="Links link">Home</a>
            <a href="" onclick="myAccFunc()" class="Links link">Websites</a>
        </div> 
        <div id="notBar">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACZSURBVGhD7djBCcJAGETh1QpiKzakxViDYCtpwSKUNKIzh9wW/pziuLwP3jFhQgzCNgAAMLijuqq7eoTlTd7mjaWb+oTnjaWn6l2clDeWhnkjB5X8jVyUNwIAsk3qFJY3bXZWi+r9oyb0Vt5YmlXvBkl5Y2mYB/Fre6neDRLytk0/rdXff+wAgJ/ggG7HOKBLiwM6AACQr7UvP+370u9envwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Menu Bar" style="width: 35px; height: 40px;" id="menu" onclick="showMenu()"> 
            <center class="center">Caleb Did This</center>
        </div> 
    </div>
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/25/12/28/iceland-1768744_960_720.jpg" id="Ice">
    <footer>
            <p class="pmargin"><span class="gray">Created and designed by</span> <span class="names">Caleb</span></p>
            <p><span class="gray">Lots of help from my uncle</span> <span class="names">Jonathan</span></p>
            <p class="icon"><span class="gray">All Icons were made by</span></p> <a href="https://icons8.com" class="a"><span class="names">Icons8</span></a>
    </footer>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Caleb.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and replaced some divs with HTML5 markup that is going to show where things have gone wrong (see my comments in the HTML for details):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Caleb Did This</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Caleb.css">
</head>
<body>
<header> <!-- div class="header" replaced with HTML5 element -->
<aside> <!-- div class="mySidebar" replaced with aside element -->
<!-- WARNING: Header element still open! -->
<a href="javascript:hideMenu()"class="Links" id="close">Close <b>X</b></a>
<a href="" class="Links link">About</a>
<a href="index.html" class="Links link">Home</a>
<a href="" onclick="myAccFunc()" class="Links link">Websites</a>
</aside> <!-- aside element closed -->
<main> <!-- div class="notBar" replaced with main element -->
<!-- WARNING: Header element still open! -->
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIAAAAyCAYAAAAeP4ixAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAACZSURBVGhD7djBCcJAGETh1QpiKzakxViDYCtpwSKUNKIzh9wW/pziuLwP3jFhQgzCNgAAMLijuqq7eoTlTd7mjaWb+oTnjaWn6l2clDeWhnkjB5X8jVyUNwIAsk3qFJY3bXZWi+r9oyb0Vt5YmlXvBkl5Y2mYB/Fre6neDRLytk0/rdXff+wAgJ/ggG7HOKBLiwM6AACQr7UvP+370u9envwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" alt="Menu Bar" style="width: 35px; height: 40px;" id="menu" onclick="showMenu()"> 
<center class="center">Caleb Did This</center>
</header> <!-- Attempt to close page header with main element open... Oops! -->
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/25/12/28/iceland-1768744_960_720.jpg" id="Ice">
<footer>
<p class="pmargin"><span class="gray">Created and designed by</span>
<span class="names">Caleb</span></p>
<p><span class="gray">Lots of help from my uncle</span>
<span class="names">Jonathan</span></p>
<p class="icon"><span class="gray">All Icons were made by</span></p>
<a href="https://icons8.com" class="a"><span class="names">Icons8</span></a>
</footer>
</main> <!-- Attempt to close main element although others have been closed prior to this - Oops...! -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="Caleb.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You have actually misplaced the various divs here (especially the closing elements). Replacing them by native HTML5 elements should reveal what's going on - see my comments for problems that are occurring.
You need to clean that up and properly place those elements (you cannot nest an aside or main section in a header element). That requires to rotate various section of your document to their correct places.